# What is the return of array.push() in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I saw these code lines in cryptozombies.io:

```
uint id = zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna)) - 1;
zombieToOwner[id] = msg.sender;
```

I wouldn't have had a problem had there not been "- 1" after the push() function. I believe the return value of the push function has something to do with the index of the inserted object. Why is there a "-1"?
Is the return value index of the next free spot available to insert the next object in the array?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html):

> **push**:
> Dynamic storage arrays and `bytes` (not `string`) have a member function called `push()` that you can use to append a zero-initialised element at the end of the array. It returns a reference to the element, so that it can be used like `x.push().t = 2` or `x.push() = b`.

The function returns the new length of the array. So if there is 1 element in the array already, and I push another, that push will return the new length, which is 2. Since arrays are zero-indexed you have to subtract one from the length to get the index of the last element, which is what the code sample you posted is doing.

Edit: As pointed out by @user8555937, this is no longer true as of Solidity 0.6.0. The push function no longer has a return value

Comment: This is no longer valid for solidity 0.6.0: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/87791/83404

Answer (score 12):

Solidity 0.6.0 has included some [breaking changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.2/060-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes) :

> The function **push(value)** for dynamic storage arrays does not return
> the new length anymore (it returns nothing).

The [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#array-members) now reads as is :

> **push(x)**:
> Dynamic storage arrays and bytes (not string) have a member function called push(x) that you can use to append a given element at
> the end of the array. The function returns nothing.

You must now use the `.length` attributes.
In your case :

```
zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna));
uint id = zombies.length - 1;
```

Answer (score 11):

The `array.push()` function is only available for storage arrays that are dynamically sized. (e.g. you can't do `array.push()` on `bytes32[10] array` as that is statically sized).

In those cases the `push` function returns the new length of the array so the last index is always the length -1 since indexes start from 0 not 1 ;

You can check it here if you want : 
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html?highlight=array#members

Answer (score 0):

I think `.push()` really means append a new element in array in most other languages.

In order to return the length of the array, it really makes more sense to have `.length`.