# Can anyone please explain me the following solidity code?

Tags: solidity

What is the use of -1 in  instructorAccts.push(_address) -1?

```
function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string _fName, string _lName) public {
    var instructor = instructors[_address];        
    instructor.age = _age;
    instructor.fName = _fName;
    instructor.lName = _lName;

    instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
}
```

Comment: See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40312/what-is-the-return-of-array-push-in-solidity

Comment: My guess is `-1` was blindly copied from another example. `push()-1` corresponds to the row in the array occupied by the appended element. As @goodvibration points out, the result of this work isn't assigned to anything (e.g. `uint position = array.push(value) -1`) so the extra work is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `instructorAccts.push(_address)` equals to the length of the `instructorAccts` array **after** pushing the `_address` item into it.

The expression `instructorAccts.push(_address) - 1` equals to the length of the `instructorAccts` array **before** pushing the `_address` item into it.

In your example, since this value is not stored or used in any manner, this expression has no effect.